# Increase drawing canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/98Bgq/

And I need to Increase drawing canvas for 550px of width and 400px height, and something tells me that this line:

```
    var arcCount = colors.length;
var arcAngle = Math.PI * 2 / arcCount;
var cx = 150;
var cy = 150;
var radius = 75;
var lineWidth = 25;
```

And I don't know how to do that, someone can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get the canvas DOM element and change its `width` and `height` properties.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = 550;
canvas.height = 400;
```

Comment: +1 Correct.  Also worth mentioning: when you resize the canvas element all the drawings are erased so you will either need to resize first or redraw after resizing.